# HashSet is empty

Tags: java, android

Why is my `HashSet<Circle>` empty?

```
    LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(),mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
    GoogleMap googleMap = mSupportMapFragment.getMap();

    HashSet<Circle> circles = new HashSet<>();

    if (!circles.isEmpty()) {
        for (Circle circle : circles) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + circles.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (!circle.getCenter().equals(currentLocation)) {
                circle.remove();
                circles.remove(circle);
            }
        }
    }

    Log.d(TAG_MAP, "" + circles.isEmpty() + " " + circles.size());

    Circle circle = googleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .radius(CONSTANT.RADIUS)
            .strokeColor(Color.parseColor(CONSTANT.RADIUS_COLOR))
            .strokeWidth(CONSTANT.RADIUS_BORDER)
            .center(currentLocation));

    circles.add(circle);
```

I mean I even added a `Circle` object to it. I don't know what's wrong. Plus the circle gets drawn on my map

Comment: @Titus why the downvote. please understand my code first. That part is right. it will be true the next time my method reruns. That part is only for undrawing the previous circle

Comment: I don't think you should claim that parts of your code are "right" when they're clearly not working as you expect them to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new - and empty - set each time the code runs:

```
HashSet<Circle> circles = new HashSet<>();
if (!circles.isEmpty()) {
    // You'll never get in here...
}
```

If you want to maintain the same set across calls, you'll need it to be a field, not a local variable.